# How to configure CORS to OpenERP 7?

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, cors, odoo, openerp-7

I am building a web service on OpenERP 7, using web controller. No problem when testing from POSTman, but on the website I get:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I know it's a cross domains request issue, but I don't know how to configure CORS on OpenERP v7. In version 8 I can setup CORS on routing, but I have no idea how to configure it on v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by calling werkzeug custom Response object:

```
return werkzeug.wrappers.Response(json_response, headers=[('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'), ('Content-Length', len(json_response))])
```

Comment: Where did you add that?

Comment: @EthanFurman Its been a long time, but I think this is the response of my api method